# Is it possible to get a security's Bid & Ask Prices in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Trading View's supercharts do display bid and ask prices.
How can I retrieve this data for a security in pinescript?
I mean, it is possible to get the current price as well ...

I did not find any solution. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it is impossible to get the bid and ask price of an instrument in Pine